# Why hasn't Israel fought alongside America in any of its wars in the Middle East?

Tags: united-states, israel

It is often claimed that Israel is America's "greatest ally" in the Middle East. In fact, the relationship between Israel and America is perhaps the closest relationship between two countries in modern history. The US provides unprecedented political and military support to Israel, much of which is without any conditions.

Despite this, it is my understanding that Israel has not assisted the US in any of its major military confrontations in the Middle East since the end of the Cold War. These include, for instance, the first and second Iraq Wars, the War in Afghanistan and the operations against ISIS. This is despite many of America's other more distant allies (e.g., France, Britain, Canada, to name a few), some of which have a weaker military than the IDF, being allies in these wars.

It is interesting to note that for some of these wars, [notably the Iraq War](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHzSr52fZLQ&t=11s), Israeli officials were actively goading Washington into invading, but did not actively partake in hostilities during the war.

I am seeking an answer which could explain some reasons for this.

Comment: "assistance" does not always include actual fighting troops. I imagine there was buttloads of intel flowing from Israel to Washington.

Comment: Voting to close because this doesn't look like a question, just a writeup to push your opinions.

Comment: I am not really sure how Israel and the USA have the closest relationship of any countries in modern history. First, you have all the countries in the European Union: so close that they share a common currency, have almost open borders to most effects, and even have a supranational parliament where they all vote on rules that will bind all of them. Then, you have the USA and the small island nations that are in compacts of free association with it, like Palau: the USA is explicitly in charge of their national defense, and their residents are able to benefit from many US government programs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There seems to have generally been mutual agreement that active US-Israeli military cooperation in the wider region is not in the best interest of either party.

In the case of the 1991 invasion of Iraq, [Wikipedia spells out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraqi_rocket_attacks_on_Israel) a clear reason: the US kept Israel out of the action **in order not to lose support from Muslim countries**.

> The strategic and political goal of the Iraqi campaign [of missile attacks on Israel] was to provoke an Israeli military response and potentially jeopardize the United States-led coalition against Iraq, which had full backing and/or extensive contributions from an overwhelming majority of the states of the Muslim world and would have suffered immense diplomatic and material losses if Muslim-majority states rescinded their support due to the political situation of the ongoing Israeli–Palestinian conflict.

In relation to the fight against ISIS, [an article](http://cgsrs.org/publications/31) by Arianna Scocchera quotes experts like Lorenzo Vidino who explain that **Israel "adopted a strategy of non-intervention beyond its borders**" for its own strategic reasons. This article also cites a dynamic similar to the above by suggesting that key partners like Turkey might withdraw if Israel got involved. Scochera concludes:

> The US’ choice to adopt a policy of restraint toward a possible Israeli involvement is a safe and cautious strategy. A change in such stance would not only cause the derailment of the US-led coalition but it would also increase the level of hostility in the region with the consequent risk of a degeneration of the already strained Israeli-Arab relations into a wider, large-scale conflict.